# Laravel 5.3 unauthorized() AuthenticationException fatal error

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, exception, upgrade

I've followed [Laravel 5.3 upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade), which says to add an `unauthenticated` method in `App\Exceptions\Handler`.

However, I get the following error when it gets called by the Auth system:

> FatalThrowableError in Handler.php line 59:
>       Type error: Argument 2 passed to App\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated() must be an instance of App\Exceptions\AuthenticationException, instance of Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException given, called in /Users/Username/Development/ProjectName/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php on line 135

I've been searching for the last half hour and couldn't find a solution.

Any help?

Comment: Either add `use App\Exceptions\AuthenticationException;` at the beggining of the file that uses the `AuthenticationException`, or change the `AuthenticationException` to `\App\Exceptions\AuthenticationException` where you use it inside your code.

Comment: I didn't create an AuthenticationException class (I didn't need it and the Laravel upgrade guide didn't mention it), it is supposed to be provided by Laravel itself.

Comment: Can you check the `app/Http/Kernel.php` if the `can` middleware points to `\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class` defined in `protected $routeMiddleware` array like this `'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had to put this project away for a while.

Yes, though, it does point to that class:

`'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check how your Handler.php file compares to the 5.3 branch version here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.3/app/Exceptions/Handler.php

Note the unauthenticated() method in Handler.php expects an instance of `\Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException`. Make sure `use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;` is included at the top of the file.

Comment: It was actually very different! My bad, I'm still a newbie in Laravel.
Updating it fixed the issue. Thanks Jon!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i just deleted whoops... or restore the default Handler.php

Answer (score 0):

I had this `Error 500` inexplicable issue while upgrading from Laravel 5.2 to 5.3. No laravel error logs in `storage/logs`, no Apache error logs. no issue with `.env`, debug was turned on, no broken `.htaccess` directives, plus `php artisan` could not run. Tried everything until I looked in the PHP error logs and found:

```php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant 'Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException' in C:\code\laravel-project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:79
```

So I did what @jon suggested and compared my Handler.php file with the fresh laravel one and found this:

In your App/Exceptions/Handler.php make sure that the classes in the `$dontreport` array are referenced as either strings in quotes:

```php
        '\Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException',
        '\Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException',
        '\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException',
        '\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException',
        '\Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException',
        '\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException',
```

or this way:

```php
        \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
        \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
        \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException::class,
        \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class,
```

For some reason I found mine to not have the quotes and fixing that got rid of the `Error 500`.